# LIKE comparison with IN operator

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to perform a `LIKE` style comparison with an `IN` operator e.g.:

```
select *
from tbl1
where tbl1.value_to_check in (select allowed_str from allowedvalues)
```

Where allowed values could contain the following `allowed_str`:

```
ab% (allow any string starting ab)
%ab (allow any string ending ab)
```

The above query obviously does not work in this way however is there a way of achieving this using SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `IN` does not support this. Try:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM dbo.tbl1 AS t1
INNER JOIN dbo.allowedvalues AS a
ON t1.value_to_check LIKE '%' + a.allowed_str + '%';
```

As Damien points out, if you are storing `ab%` and `%ab` separately, rather than just `ab` on its own, then you just need:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM dbo.tbl1 AS t1
INNER JOIN dbo.allowedvalues AS a
ON t1.value_to_check LIKE a.allowed_str;
```

Comment: If you've moved to the join style, and `allowed_str` does indeed contain `ab%`, then there's no need to add the extra `%`s, is there?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever if `t1.value_to_check` contains `absence` and `flab` and both are expected to match, I don't think you could leave out either `%`. I suppose you could use an `OR` and check each case separately, so that an index might help part of the query, but I'm not sure if that would be better overall.

Comment: I meant that the OP seemed to indicate that this column already contains a `like`-style expression

Comment: Ah I see. Then yes I guess you wouldn't need the `'%'` above - I would expect though that it would be better to store `ab` than to store `%ab` and `ab%` separately, but it depends on requirements (e.g. are there cases where `bc%` is expected but `%bc` is not wanted).

Comment: Ah - classic case of looking at a problem for so long I couldn't see the answer.  And can do a Left Join to simulate 'NOT IN'

Comment: And yes, the column would already contain a like style expression however the logic is the same

Answer (score 0):

I believe the exists clause matches better with the original query.

```
select *
from tbl1
where exists (select 1
              from allowedvalues 
              where tbl1.value_to_check like '%' + a.allowed_str + '%';)
```

Note: this will cause a table scan on tbl1 (and might be very slow)